# Show iAdBanner on top of nav bar

Tags: iphone, iad

i want to show iAd Banner on top of Nav Bar.

I tried with the following code

```
Devanagari *viewController = [[Devanagari alloc]init];
viewController.delegate = self;

// _adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,40)];
  _adView.frame = CGRectOffset(_adView.frame, 0, -50);
_adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
_adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
_adView.delegate=self;
self.bannerIsVisible=YES;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                        initWithRootViewController:viewController];
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
[navigationController release];
```

didn't worked.

Is there any way that i can show iAdBanner View on top of the view and then right below nav bar.

Thanks for help.